# change two or more values of an object by a condition

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a table with elements, in which for each element I have an initial counter at 1 and two buttons, one to increase by one and the other to decrease by one, in the same way for each element I have a price, each element is an object that contains the quantity, the price among other things. I am using redux and with the increase button on +1 I make a send to the reducer, where I am adding 1 to the value of the counter, this works fine, I already manage to change the quantity, which is to multiply the price by the quantity, the problem that now when the quantity is 2, the price is the same, when changing the quantity to 3, it already shows me the price but only for 2 products, since the quantity is 4, it shows me the price of 3 products. How can i fix this? Add two prices to the product object, the price that changes and the Single price that does not change so that it multiplies this by the quantity.

With this code it increases the quantity and multiplies the price by the quantity, but only when the quantity is three, being two, it keeps the same price

```
case types.increase:{
            return {
                ...state,
                productsCart: state.productsCart.map(product =>  product.id === action.payload ? { ...product, cantidad: product.cantidad + 1, price: product.cantidad * product.precioUnidad}  : product ),
            }
    }
```

This is the component where I show all the elements and add to the cart with the data of each product:

```
const Product = ({name, brand, price, image, id}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleAddCart = () => {
        dispatch(addProductsCart({price,image, name, id, precioUnidad: price ,cantidad: 1}))
    }
  return (
    
        <div className="product__content__card">
            <div className="card__image">
                <img 
                    src={image}
                />
            </div>

            <div className="card__body">
                <p className="name">{name}</p>
                <p className="brand">{brand}</p>
                <p className="price">${price}</p>

                <button
                    onClick={handleAddCart}
                >Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You mean you need to calculate the total price of each product ?, could you please add the product object structure

Comment: Yes, the price of each product but multiplied by the number of products. I already half solved it, it already multiplies it but when the quantity is 3 it puts the price as if it were 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that you're calculating the price based on the cantidad you had in your product, not the updated one.

When you are calculating the price you're doing:

```
price: product.cantidad * product.precioUnidad
```

When you should be doing:

```
price: (product.cantidad + 1) * product.precioUnidad
```

Hope it helps!